# modifying xml files from a folder in java

Tags: java, xml

As i am new to java i need some help of modifying xml file using java .i am having some xml files in a folder. i want to add a child tag with another child tag.i have tried to get all file by using File. and for parsing and modification purpose i am using DocumentBuildFactory and Element. but at parse method of DocumentBuilder the file is not coming its showing null.

**Input:-**

```
<Student>
  <personal-details>
    <name>abc</name>
    <age>21</age>
  </personal-details>
  <address>
    <zip>560037</zip>
  </address>
</Student>
```

i want to add a child element inside the address tag and expect output like below:-

**Output:-**

```
<Student>
  <personal-details>
    <name>abc</name>
    <age>21</age>
  </personal-details>
  <address>
    <place>
        <line1>some lane</line1>
    </place>
    <zip>560037</zip>
  </address>
</Student>
```

the java code i have written is below

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
public class AddTag {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\xmlfiles\\");
    File listOfFiles [] =folder.listFiles();
    String fileName = null;
    for(int i=0;i<listOfFiles.length;i++)
    {
        fileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
    try{
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(folder+"\\"+fileName);
    System.out.println(doc); // op:-[#document: null]
    Node address = doc.getElementsByTagName("address").item(0);

    Element place = doc.createElement("place");
    place.appendChild(doc.createElement("line1").appendChild(doc.createTextNode("some lane")));
    address.appendChild(place);
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(folder+"\\"+fileName));
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    System.out.println("Done");
    }catch(Exception e){
        }
     }   
  }
}
```

but i am getting out put like below without **line1** tag:-

```
<Student>
   <personal-details>
      <name>abc</name>
      <age>21</age>
   </personal-details>
   <address>
    <zip>560037</zip>
    <place>some lane</place>
   </address>
</Student>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
place.appendChild(doc.createElement("line1").appendChild(doc.createTextNode("some lane")));
```

Appends the "some lane" text node to the Place node. appendChild returns the node that has been added as per the documentation:

*http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#appendChild(org.w3c.dom.Node)
Returns: The node added.*

So split this up and it should work.
Try something like this:

```
Node line1 = doc.createElement("line1");
line1.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("some lane"));
place.appendChild(line1);
```